# Find if there is any repeat content in a list and remove repeated instances

Tags: javascript, jquery, duplicates

Basically what I'm trying to do is identify if there is any duplicate content from a list of items that all share the same class, and then remove any duplicates.

Here's my attempt so far but has been unsuccessful:

```
var listItemContent = $(".featured-listing").textContent;
if (listItemContent === listItemContent) {
    $('.featured-listing').hide();
}
```

This isn't really working, and I'm not surprised as js is not my strong suit and even reading it it looks like it would take the content of an instance of ".featured-listing", compare it to itself and then hide it, resulting in all instances of that class being hidden. The problem is I'm not really sure how to:

1. Check if DIFFERENT instances of that class have matching text content
2. Remove any duplicated content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this snippet:

```js
var listItemContents = [];

$(".featured-listing li").each(function() {
    var text = $(this).text();
    
    if (listItemContents.indexOf(text) == -1) {
      listItemContents.push(text);
    }
    else {
      $(this).remove();
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="featured-listing">
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
  <li>Text 3</li>
  <li>Text 1</li>
  <li>Text 4</li>
  <li>Text 2</li>
</ul>
```

It just loop through all items checking their content by an array. If the text isn't found in the array, it adds the item. If it is found, it removes the list item.

I'm not sure if that html is like yours since you didn't added it in your post. If you do, we can have a clearer idea of what would works better for you.

Comment: This makes sense and looks like it should work, thanks for the quick response! The html is essentially the same, sorry for not posting it though. I'm getting an odd console error when trying this though and it looks like something is removing the [] brackets on the var declaration. I get a console error for "Unexpected token ;" and it looks like that var is rendering out as: "var listItemContents = ;". I'm going to deep dive and see if I can figure this out but in case that looks like a familiar issue I'm accepting suggestions haha.

Comment: @tganyan what do you mean as *"rendering out as"* ? How are you rendering that code, in any kind of a template or a server side language? That `[]` needs to be there! hahaha

Comment: Sorry, poor word choice, I just meant that something was removing the brackets from that variable declaration before the code runs. What was happening was unique to my environment; I'm working in kind of an old token template where all the tokens follow the syntax of "[SOME-PROPERTY]" so the brackets are reserved for that. In this case I had to use "new Array" in order to get around it. Otherwise, this works exactly as needed, thanks!

Comment: @tganyan oh i see. ok then! glad to help

Answer (score 1):

Get all the `featured-listings`. Define a main `object` which holds all the texts and then delete an element if there is the same text:

```
var elements = {};

$('.featured-listsing').each(function () {

    var currentText = $(this).text();

    if ( elements[currentText] )

        $(this).remove();

    else

        elements[currentText] = true;

});
```

Comment: Hi @quirimmo, change the name of `var` `elements` to `seen`. In your current code `seen` is not defined. By the way, nice solution ;)

Comment: Oh thanks a lot I defined a variable and used another one :D

Comment: I know, no worries, but you still have a `seen` variable in the `else` field :)

Comment: Ahhaha thanks a lot! A lot.of times I update it using the phone and the edit is awful -.-

Comment: I supposed something like that, now it is OK. Regards ;)

Comment: Thanks to you and have a nice day :)

Answer (score 1):

You can filter your `jQuery` list object taking those that are repeated and hide them. Check the next `fiddle`, the technique is to check those items that have a previous sibling with the same text content and create a new `jQuery` list with them:

```js
let items = $(".featured-listing li");

let repes = items.filter((ind, itm) => $(itm).prevAll(`:contains(${itm.innerText})`).length);

repes.remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="featured-listing">
  <li>1 - Content 01</li>
  <li>2 - Content 02</li>
  <li>1 - Content 01</li>
  <li>3 - Content 03</li>
  <li>4 - Content 04</li>
  <li>2 - Content 02</li>
  <li>5 - Content 05</li>
  <li>6 - Content 06</li>
  <li>2 - Content 02</li>
  <li>7 - Content 07</li>
</ul>
```